# How to put PHP class definition in include file

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, having trouble when I move a class definition out of my "main" page and into an include file.

Suppose I have main.php, with the below contents. It works fine:

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
    public $var = 'a def value';

    public function displayVar() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}
?>
<html>
<h1>blah blah blah</h1>
</html>
```

But now suppose that I try removing the class definition and putting it in a **separate** file, so that the main.htm now looks like:

```
<?php
include("classdef.php");
?>
<html>
<h1>blah blah blah</h1>
</html>
```

and classdef.php is:

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
    public $var = 'a def value';

    public function displayVar() {
    echo $this->var;
}
?>
```

Then when I view my main.php, it displays as

```
var; } } ?>
blah blah blah
```

As if the `>` character in the `$this->var` is interpreted as closing the PHP. I've had trouble searching for this, in that I don't know what the `->` operator is called.

This is PHP 5.3.3 on Apache 2.2 on Windows.

Comment: Just a hint - for files containing nothing but PHP code (class definition files for example), start with `<?php` and omit the closing tag entirely. This will help avoid any whitespace characters sneaking in at the end of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably don't start your classfile with `<?php`, but nasty `<?`, and `short_open_tags` are disabled. Fix that (make it `<?php`, leave `short_open_tags` off), and it'll work. Anything between the starting `<?` and the first `>` after that is now sent to the user and interpreted as an HTML tag (if you look in the source, you probably see your whole class definition).

Comment: No, the class file does indeed start with <?php, so I don't think that is the problem. On the other hand, something is definitely causing the ">" character to get interpreted as closing the PHP. Since my original post, I have discovered that class definition has nothing to do with it - I get the same kind of error if I simply add a comment in the include file that has a ">" character in it.

Comment: Then it escapes from PHP somewhere else. Have you looked at the source? 'cause `>` on it's own will never end PHP, only `?>` will, so by looking at the source you can see at which point your PHP starts to get interpreted as HTML.

Comment: I'm so very busted. My claim that "the class file does start with <?php" was WRONG. That assertion was based on me double checking the WRONG file. I'm now feeling super bad for wasting everyone's time and hope I don't get super chastised with down votes. All the explanations have been very helpful, but I'm accepting this one because of the mention of "short_open_tags". That explains a different problem that I hadn't even mentioned, namely, why the exact same code was working on one server (that I copied from) but not mine. It's because the source server had them enabled, but I don't.

Answer (score 6):

Your PHP isn't being interpreted (if it was a parse error problem, well, you would get a parse error). First thing I noticed is you said you put the PHP in main.**htm**. Unless you explicitely set your server to interpret .htm / .html files with PHP, your server won't know you have PHP in this file.

Edit: as I said in comments, the problem is that PHP isn't being interpreted by Apache. Here are the usual problems :

- You're not calling the script correctly, for example you are calling C:\wamp\www\yourfile.php instead of http://localhost/yourfile.php
- As Wrikken said, you are using short tags (< ? instead of < ?php)
- You gave a wrong extension to your file name

I don't think it's a quote problem, otherwise you would most likely get a parse error. I'll go with what other people said and ask you to give the HTML code generated by your PHP script (access the script through your browser and press Ctrl + U)

Comment: +1 for being the only one to pick up on the filename, which while yes there is also the typo, is the *real* root of his problem.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is the problem as the `classdef.php` file is obviously being included correctly - `var; } } ?>` in output, though where that second closing brace comes from is a mystery. I don't think we're getting the full source code. Time to start copy/pasting instead of typing

Comment: It's hard to diagnose the root of the problem without more information. The only thing we know for sure is that PHP isn't being interpreted and there are many things that can cause this : not running the script through a server (i.e. calling C:/myfile.php instead of localhost/myfile.php), using short tags (<? instead of <?php), using a wrong extension... OP is contradicting : he says his file is name main.htm but that it used to work fine. tl,dr: can't give a precise answer without more info.

Comment: Sorry about that, the main file is indeed main.php. My real files are of course much more complicated than this, and in my problem description I tried to strip everything down to the minimum necessary to duplicate the problem, and I mistakenly said main.htm when I meant main.php.

Comment: See my answer, it'll be a missing or unescaped quote character.

Answer (score 3):

It seems typo error on your classdef.php, try below:

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
    public $var = 'a def value';

    public function displayVar() {
      echo $this->var;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this be

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
    public $var = 'a def value';

    public function displayVar() {
    echo $this->var;
}
}
?>
```

You are missing a `}` for function `displayVar()`

Answer (score 0):

With the latest updates from RobC, my guess is a missing or unescaped quote character. Unless we're shown the actual source, this is my best guess.

I suggest you use an IDE or editor with syntax highlighting and the problem will become obvious.